# java replaceAll with founded value

Tags: java, regex, replace

I want to replace all occurences of insensitive phrase in text with another expression, that contains founded phrase. Example:

```
String searchQuery = "word";    
String source = "I want find WORD case insensitive, and change fonts of this word";
System.out.println(source.replaceAll("(?i)" + searchQuery, "<font color='red'>" + searchQuery + "</font>"));
```

And I want to get "I want find WORD case insensitive, and change fonts of this word".
But actually the first "WORD" becomes "word", because I replace it wrong.
How can I replace it with original word.

Comment: The answer below may fix your immediate problem, but in general if you need to update some HTML you should consider using a parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$0` in the replacement string to refer to the matched value:

```
source.replaceAll("(?i)" + searchQuery, "<font color='red'>$0</font>")
```